# Memcached (not memcache) PHP extension on Windows

Tags: php, memcached, xampp, pecl

I can't seem to find the Memcache**D** extension for PHP.

There are a few compilations of php_memcache.dll, but that's not the same.

The main thing I'm missing is [getMulti()](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getmulti.php), which doesn't exist in Memcache.

So far I found this, but there's no DLL:

http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officially - it does not exist. There are several people who have created their own DLL's though. Here is one person's blog who has created the dll:

http://trondn.blogspot.com/2010/07/libmemcached-on-win32.html

Here is a link to the repository with the source so you can build your own DLL for memcached:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~trond-norbye/libmemcached/mingw32/files

Comment: would be great is someone would release this as a compiled binary. I'll try compile and share.

Answer (score 5):

I know the memcached has some other features but its interface is nearly identical with that of memcache extension. You can very easily get away with such code and in my case it works perfectly well. If you don't have the memcached loaded create this file:

```
<?php

    class Memcached {
       const OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE = true;
       const OPT_COMPRESSION = true;
       const OPT_NO_BLOCK = true;
       //if you code relies on any other constants define them to avoid
       //undefined constant notice

       //http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php

       public $_instance;
       public function __construct() {
            $this->_instance = new Memcache;
       }

       public function __call($name, $args) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->_instance, $name), $args);
       }

       public function setOption() {}
    }
```

Either include it or configure autoloader to pick it up.
Of course you'll need a properly configured memcache instance and addServer calls but such calls should already be in the code if the codebase assumes Memcached.
I hope it helps someone/