# Manual shows memcached is a valid library

Tags: php, memcached

the php documentation for memcache and memcached shows up as two different libraries... I have downloaded the following;

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip

This is the windows binaries for `memcache` library which the documentation is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

and There is also a library for Memcached: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

So is there a valid windows binary which runs with php5.5 which enables memcached, as from reading the documentation.. This library offers more expandability

I have looked over: https://serverfault.com/questions/63383/memcache-vs-memcached about the possibilities aswell, there is no specifics on how to enable this library within php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached has no official dll release for windows.

You can either compile it yourself from the PECL source or use a precompiled dll from someone else : http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

See also : [Memcached (not memcache) PHP extension on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243745/memcached-not-memcache-php-extension-on-windows)

Comment: Ill check this out when im back in the office or on a computer, thanks!

Comment: After looking, this is offering the memcached server, and the memcache extension within php.. and not the `memcached` library for PHP

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693195/does-memcached-dll-exist

You'll have to try to compile it yourself with the link I gave if you really want it.