# Is it possible to install memcacheD (with a D) for php on windows so that I can use it with xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, memcached

I already know that it is possible to install `memcache` (not `memcached`, that is another program!) for PHP on windows to be used with `xampp`.

I am wondering if there are any solutions for a working `memcached` (mind the `d` at the end :))?

I have put several hours into this already, I have found out that you can install it with ease on linux.

And that `HHVM` has this preinstalled, you just need some dependencies such as `libmemcached` and so on.

But I develop on windows using xampp, so I would like to be able to use the `memcached` class from php on windows, too. I don't think swapping the database and using `redis` is an option for me because it is slow. 
Even thoough `phpredis` is a fast C extension, but it is incompatible with `HHVM`.

There are countless tutorials on the web marketing how to install "memcache" on windows, but they are all just for the php `memcache` class (no d), not `memcached`.

The dll file you need to copy to `D:\xampp\php\ext` only exists for `memcache` and not `memcached`.

**Can I develop with `HHVM` and `memcached` on `windows` using the php `memcached` class instead of the `memcache` one?**

Comment: I use a memcached server with windows.
You can get the server version and read the tutorial here: http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine

Comment: Yes you can install memcached, but can only use the Memcache class from php, not the memcached class which is newer.

Comment: I got, the problem is the php client. I asked a friend which works with php and he told me there isn't a php client from memcached windows. Here is also a link about:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243745/memcached-not-memcache-php-extension-on-windows