# MemcacheD PHP extension on Windows

Tags: php, memcached

I need activate `memcached` on windows. What is weird I could install server but I can't find php extension for windows. I found a lot of topics where is claimed that there is no such for this system. Anyway that were old topic and I wonder if "they" created one already?

edit:
PHP 7, w10

Comment: What version of PHP are you using. It's quite relevant

Comment: [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243745/memcached-not-memcache-php-extension-on-windows) could help it is the same suject

Comment: @Novy I saw that topic, didn't help

Comment: @RiggsFolly memcache and memcached are different packages (

Comment: may be you can check [this out](https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll) @Oleksandr Khavdiy

Answer (score 0):

I did not test because i do not have a windows machine or vm wathever. At least you can try this [git repo](https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll)

You can find a better install process [here](https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows)

If you did already try it sorry for the wast of time.